# JDK8 Functional Programming a function can throw a exception?

Tags: java-8, functional-programming

I have one requirement

1. Get the employee information from the employee repository.
2. Update the employee information with some additional information.
3. Transform the employee object to gatewayRequest object.
4. call the gateway service and get the response.
5. from the response get the return code of the gateway call.

For this requirement, i am using functional programming to achieve the result.

Here I have created the multiple functions in my Service layer

```
final Function<String, Employee> getRegisteredEmployee =
        localId -> employeeRepository.findById(employeeId).
                orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("ResourceNotFound"));

final Function<Employee, Employee> updateEmployeAddressandSave =
        employe -> {
            String status = //some logic to identitythe Employee
            Employee e = new Employee(employee.getName(),employee.getAddress ,"INTERNAL_EMPLOYEE")
            Employee emp = employeeRepository.save(e);
            return emp;
};
```

Likewise, I created different functions and then I am using the `andThen` method of the functional interface to get the results

```
getRegisteredEmployee.
       andThen(updateEmployeAddressandSave).
       andThen(transformTheEmployeeToGatewayRequest).
       andThen(allgateWayClinet).apply(12);
```

According to the functional programming model, a function should take input and give some output; it should not throw any exception. But in my example `getRegisteredEmployee` throws an exception if employee is not found.

Hence, am I not following the functional programming core principles?

what is the alternate way to throw the exception in functional programming?

Comment: You can always define your own `@FunctionalInterface` and declare that the non-default method throw an exception.

Comment: can you please point me some example as i am new to FunctionalProgramming

Comment: There is nothing wrong exceptions in FP code. Real FP languages usually have constructs like `Either[result value | error type]`, however, that’s just a different way to model the same thing. When you consider return value and the set of potentially thrown exceptions as the result, you may notice that *unchecked* exceptions are a problem here, as you have no control over the set.

Answer (score 1):

While not adhering to principles, it is technically possible to create a functional interface that will throw a checked exception.

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface CheckedFunction<A, B> {
  B apply(A a) throws Exception;
}
```

(Since you're using `andThen` you'll need to implement that as well using the `default` keyword. Remember, though, that the functional interface must have at most one non-default method, so you'll have to provide the `andThen` implementation defaulted.)

So, as an example, you would be able to do something like:

```
public void doThings(Integer id) throws Exception {

    CheckedFunction<Integer, Employee> fn = (id) -> someMethodThatReturnsAnEmployeeOrThrows(id);

    fn.apply(id)
      .map( ... ) // ... some other stuff

}
```

As I mentioned, this doe not adhere to principles; I only go down this path when I absolutely have to bubble the exception up. Other Java 8 features such as `Optional` are more appropriate in this situation. (Since it looks like you're using spring's JPA implementation, you can define your `findById` method to return an `Optional<Employee>`.)

Comment: Thanks for the idea,Can you help me in pointing one end to end example which helps me in better understanding the solution,Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Method getRegisteredEmployee can return an Optional object instead of throwing an exception.

```
 final Function<String, Employee> getRegisteredEmployee =
        localId -> employeeRepository.findById(employeeId);

final Function<Employee, Employee> updateEmployeAddressandSave =
        employe -> {
            if(employe.isPresent()) {
                employe.get();
               ...
               String status = //some logic to identitythe Employee
               Employee e = new Employee(employee.getName(),employee.getAddress ,"INTERNAL_EMPLOYEE")
               Employee emp = employeeRepository.save(e);
               return new Optional(emp);
            } else {
               return Optional.empty();
            }
};

etc...
```

Comment: I'd be willing to consider this an answer and not just a comment if you'd offer an example of what you meant.

Comment: Yes but where i can throw exception ?

Comment: You can consider the [Either](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_either) pattern instead. There's [Option](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_option) and there's [Either](http://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_either) patterns.

Comment: i can return Optional but in functional chaining some where i have to throw exception , when no employee found i have to throw

Comment: Your final apply() method can throw an exception.

Comment: @FabienMIFSUD can you please point me one full example to better understand

Comment: I'm not sure my suggestion is the good one because you will not be able to know wich one of calling methods did fail if you throw one exception at the end. Keep your code as it is or implement your own methods instead of usinf Function<>